# Passing data from MATLAB GUI to another function

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I have a matlab `GUI` (Compare2ImagesGUI) which gets called within another `GUI` (DistanceOrderGUI) and should return a variable based on some interaction with a user.

Here is a snippet of how the `Compare2ImagesGUI` gets called:

```
a=1;b=2;
handles.a = a;
handles.b = b;

result = Compare2ImagesGUI('DistanceOrderGUI', handles)
```

And here is what it does when it opens:

```
function Compare2ImagesGUI_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to Compare2ImagesGUI (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for Compare2ImagesGUI
%handles.output = hObject;
a = varargin{2}.a;
b = varargin{2}.b;
handles.a = a;
handles.b = b;
handles.ima = varargin{2}.ims{a};
handles.imb = varargin{2}.ims{b};
init(hObject,handles);

% UIWAIT makes Compare2ImagesGUI wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
uiwait(hObject);
```

this is the init function:

```
function init(hObject,handles)

imshow(handles.ima,'Parent',handles.axes1);
handles.current = handles.a;

% handles.ims=ims; handles.gt=gt; 
% handles.folderN=folderN; handles.name=dirnames{folderN};

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);
```

When the user finishes interacting he presses a button and the `GUI` should close and return the value to its calling function:

```
% --- Executes on button press in pushbutton3.
function pushbutton3_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to pushbutton3 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject,handles);

% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = Compare2ImagesGUI_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.current

delete(handles.Compare2ImagesGUI);


% --- Executes when user attempts to close figure1.
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

if isequal(get(hObject,'waitstatus'),'waiting')
    uiresume(hObject);
else
    delete(hObject);
end
```

I followed instruction on how to structure this code found [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=lSGEIZscN_gC&pg=PA221&lpg=PA221&dq=waitstatus+matlab&source=bl&ots=Ahqoo9LsOG&sig=sD7rZEjAFcrMeaOwoFhLmVJK0fM&hl=en&sa=X&ei=8ikNU877F9jZoATY1oKYCQ&ved=0CCkQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=waitstatus%20matlab&f=false) and [here](http://blogs.mathworks.com/videos/2010/02/12/advanced-getting-an-output-from-a-guide-gui/), nonetheless I get this weird error and am really clueless on what to do about it:

```
Error using hg.uicontrol/get
The name 'waitstatus' is not an accessible property for an instance of
class 'uicontrol'.

Error in Compare2ImagesGUI>figure1_CloseRequestFcn (line 127)
if isequal(get(hObject,'waitstatus'),'waiting')

Error in Compare2ImagesGUI>pushbutton3_Callback (line 118)
figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject,handles);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 96)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in Compare2ImagesGUI (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
@(hObject,eventdata)Compare2ImagesGUI('pushbutton3_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


Error using waitfor
Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

Note that line 127 is in the `function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, handles)` function.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Did the solution work for you?

Comment: Yes, the version of `figure1_CloseRequestFcn` should have solved it, so I'd be curious to know what didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Usually a [`CloseRequestFcn`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/the-figure-close-request-function.html) is not called via a `uicontrol` that you created, but rather when:

- you close the figure using the built-in figure controls (e.g the "X" box at the top, or the figure menu)
- `close` is called for your the figure
- quit MATLAB

What happens is that `pushbutton3_Callback` passes *its own handle* rather the *figure's handle* in `hObject` to `figure1_CloseRequestFcn`.  The problem is that the `'waitstatus'` property only belongs to a `figure`.

The solution is to either modify `pushbutton3_Callback` to pass the figure handle, or modify `pushbutton3_Callback` to just use the figure handle.  For example:

```
% --- Executes when user attempts to close figure1.
function figure1_CloseRequestFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to figure1 (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

hFig = ancestor(hObject,'Figure');
if isequal(get(hFig,'waitstatus'),'waiting')
    uiresume(hFig);
else
    delete(hFig);
end
```

NOTE: I added and `eventdata` argument to `figure1_CloseRequestFcn`, which seemed to be missing from your code. (Normally it is defined as `@(hObject,eventdata)guitest('figure1_CloseRequestFcn',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))`).